# Using OWIN Identity v2 Claims to track custom properties in WebAPI2 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, membership

getting my head wrapped around the new Identity framework and am trying to figure out how best to handle custom user properties. I have tried extending the IdentityUser, which works to store the information, but so far is requiring an additional db call to get the property back out. I am looking at switching to using claims to store/retrieve this information.

First, the specific prop I want to store/retrieve is not unique to an individual user (many to one). Consider grouping users together in a custom Group structure. I want to store the GroupId for use in other related entities.

I am able to store the GroupId (currently using the ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier which I don't think it the correct usage for that type, but...). But, when I go to retrieve that value, the claim type isn't found in the claims collection. It's in the db, so I know it's there. I'm missing something.

FWIW: Since it's WebAPI, I'm not using a traditional sign-in. I'm using token auth.

When I create the user, I have something like:

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateUserAsync(string email, string password, string groupId)
    {
        var userId = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(DateTime.UtcNow).ToString(); // yes, it's a NoSQL store
        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            Id = userId,
            UserName = email
        };

        var claim = new IdentityUserClaim { ClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, ClaimValue = groupId, UserId = userId, Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(DateTime.UtcNow).ToString() };
        user.Claims.Add(claim);

        var result = await _UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
        return result;
    }
```

That creates what looks to be an appropriate db entry.

When I retrieve the value, I get null reference errors. Here's that code via an extension method:

```
public static string GetGroupId(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var claimsIdentity = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        return claimsIdentity == null ? "" : claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    }
```

The error hits when trying to get Value as the FindFirst is returning a null value.

Any hints or better/best practices here would be appreciated! Honestly, I'd prefer to just store this on the `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser` object, but I can't find a simple way of retrieving that of User.Identity in my api controller context without an additional call to the db.

Answer (score 5):

Your gut feeling about storing extra data as a claim is correct, but implementation is a bit broken.

I recommend to have your own claim types created for your domain information. Do not reuse claim types provided from framework. Reason for that is `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` represents User.Id. 
The framework itself adds standard list of claims to all users:

- User.Id => represented as `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`
- Username => represented as 'ClaimTypes.Name'
- ProviderName => represented as `ClaimTypes.ProviderName` (not 100% sure about this one); Usually value is "ASP.NET Identity"
- SecurityStamp value (not sure what the claim type name for it)
- All the roles assigned to the user are stored as `ClaimTypes.Role`

So in your case you have tried to overwrite claim with value of  `User.Id` which is quite important, I would think -)

Now, let's try to fix your coding problems. When you create a user, you add claims after you have created a user object:

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateUserAsync(string email, string password, string groupId)
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            Id = userId,
            UserName = email
        };

    var userCreateResult = await _UserManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
    if(!userCreateResult.IsSuccess)
    {
        // user creation have failed - need to stop the transaction
        return userCreateResult;
    }

    // better to have a class with constants representing your claim types
    var groupIdClaim = new Claim("MyApplication:GroupClaim", ObjectId.GenerateNewId(DateTime.UtcNow).ToString());

    // this will save the claim into the database. Next time user logs in, it will be added to Principal.Identity
    var claimAddingResult = await _UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, groupIdClaim);
    return claimAddingResult;
}
```

As for extension methods I usually work with `IPrincipal` or `ClaimsPrincipal`. But `IIdentity` is also workable. Don't forget you can access `ClaimsPrincipal` anywhere by calling `ClaimsPrincipal.Current`.

This is how I usually work with extension methods:

```
public static string GetGroupId(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    var groupIdClaim = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "MyApplication:GroupClaim");
    if (personIdClaim != null)
    {
        return groupIdClaim.Value;
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

So in your methods you'd retrieve assigned `groupId` for the currently logged in user like this:

```
var groupId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.GetGroupId();
```

Hope this clarifies your confusion!